# Text appears on :active (masonry)

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity, masonry

I am trying to create an effect where the images of a Masonry constructed gallery are at 0.2 opacity, and goes to 1 opacity on :hover.

Then if an image is :active it fades to 0.7 opacity and the image location "Petra, Jordan" appears over the image.

I currently have everything working as needed except the text part. How can I create this effect with CSS or JS? Thanks in advance.

```
<article class="bottomcontent"> 
        <h2>Visuals</h2>
    <section id="photos"></section>
</article>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#photos').append( 
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals1.jpg" alt="Petra, Jordan"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals2.jpg" alt="img02"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals3.jpg" alt="img03"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals4.jpg" alt="img04"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals5.jpg" alt="img05"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals6.jpg" alt="img06"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals7.jpg" alt="img07"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals8.jpg" alt="img08"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals9.jpg" alt="img09"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals10.jpg" alt="img10"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals11.jpg" alt="img11"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals12.jpg" alt="img12"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals13.jpg" alt="img13"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals15.jpg" alt="img15"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals16.jpg" alt="img16"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals17.jpg" alt="img17"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals18.jpg" alt="img18"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals19.jpg" alt="img19"/>',
    '<img src="/visuals/visuals20.jpg" alt="img20"/>'
    );
  }
);    
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#photos img {
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
opacity: 0.2;
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

#photos img:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

#photos img:active {
opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle link for your code, it will be easier

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m77Lucnt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jose_mar/c4gefged/)

you could use `:after` and `data-` to do this.
But img does not support `:after` or `:before`, so I wrap the img with a div. Here is the code:

```
      <div data-text="Display">
        <img id="text" style="width:100px;height:100px"/>
      </div>

      [data-text]{
           position:relative;
           display:inline-block;
      }
      [data-text] :hover{
           opacity:0.3;
      }
      [data-text]:hover::after{
           content:attr(data-text);
           position:relative;
           left:-65px;
           bottom:60px;
      }
```

Comment: But how do I wrap the images with a div when the HTML only contains a <section id=>?

Comment: you use `$.append()` to append an img to `<section>` , so you can use it to wrap the `<img>`.  Wrap it literally.

Comment: When I wrapped each photo in a div (because each photo has different text), my four columns collapsed into one. How do I restore that?

Second: you used left/bottom px to get the text over the box. Is there a more elegant solution to getting the text centered over its parent photo?

Thanks.

Comment: This resolves the second broblem: [Check This new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4gefged/1/), but for the first one, can you give a visible example in jsfiddle ?

Comment: You are the man. I resolved the first issue; it was a webkit backface visibility issue.

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/vojzubcg/